# Trying to run a simple express server on a Docker, but cant access any routes

Tags: javascript, express, docker

I try to run a simple container with node on it, 
I do get the log I added to `.listen(port, log)`
but I cant access it with the browser.

Im new to Docker, so maybe im missing something.

I first run `docker build -t my-node-app .` to create my image.

then I run `docker run -it --rm -name myapp -p 3000:80 my-node-app`

Then the server runs, 
I get to see the log I added in the callback of `app.listen(port ,cb)`

but when I try to open `localhost:3000`, nothing comes up.

When I run it localy on my machine without docker it works fine.

I also tried to access the url with the IP Address I found with `docker inspect myapp`, but it also didnt work out.

**Dockerfile:**

```
FROM node:4-onbuild
EXPOSE 80
```

**Node index.js:**

```
const express = require('express');

const app = express();
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000;

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    console.log('hello')
    res.send('it works!');
});

app.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log(`${process.env.NODE_ENV}server is running on port ${PORT} on ${process.platform}`);
});
```

Comment: Are you setting the `PORT` environment variable?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The syntax of the `-p` switch is: `$HOSTPORT:$CONTAINERPORT`.

Looking at that, you are mapping the **Host Port 3000**, to the **Guest Port 80**.  But, your node server isn't listening on 80; it's listening on 3000.

You can either:

- Set the `PORT` environement variable to 80 with `-e "PORT=80"` See [`ENV` switch](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#env-environment-variables)
- Have node listen on 80 by default instead of 3000
- Use `-p 3000:3000` so that you are using the right guest port

---

Additionally, you have `EXPOSE 80` set in your Dockerfile, but you still aren't exposing the right port.  Node still listens on 3000 by default according to your server code.

Also, since you also, use `-p 123:456`, you could potentially override the `EXPOSE` setting.  See: [Overriding Dockerfile image defaults](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#overriding-dockerfile-image-defaults).

Comment: So what does it mean I EXPOSE inside the Dockerfile port 80, when I run `docker run -it --rm -p 3000:3000`

Comment: @ueeieiie See my edit.  The EXPOSE should usually match your default application port.